# OpenFda data seems to grow lot each quarter

Tags: openfda

Why the data we get from openfda seems to grow a lot each quarter? The 2020Q2 openfda csv file we create is 2.3GB vs the 2019Q2 data which is 1.3GB. On the other hand, the FAERS data only changed from 118MB to 123MB in the same time period.

Answer (score 0):

> The 2020Q2 openfda csv file we create is 2.3GB vs the 2019Q2 data which is 1.3GB.

Since openFDA does not generate CSV files and we have no way of knowing how the CSV file you are referring to is created & populated, we really have no way of answering the question. Sorry about the incovenience; I wish I could be more helpful.